# Excel Macro: How can I get word header while looping to documents tables not pages

Tags: excel, vba

I have a document that goes thru excel macro to get all the tables in the word document and loop each to get the data and convert it to excel. Problem is I need to pull a data (string) inside the header of each page while looping into tables to associate the table data to its employee.

**Sample header values:**

Page 1: "Employee: Jane Motts"

Page 2: "Employee: Jane Motts"

Page 3: "Employee: Clark Wright"

Page 4: "Employee: Sam Molds" and so on..

**Sample Table Values:**

```
Date  | No. of Tardy | No. of Undertime
11/12 |      5       |      10
```

I can successfully import this word table data into excel, problem is i need the employee name as well like this:

**Desired Import Output:**

```
Name         |  Date  | No. of Tardy | No. of Undertime
Jane Motts   |  1/12  |      1       |      6 
Jane Motts   |  2/12  |      2       |      7 
Jane Motts   |  3/12  |      3       |      8 
Clark Wright |  1/12  |      4       |      6 
Sam Molds    |  2/12  |      7       |      7 
Sam Molds    |  3/12  |      8       |      8
```

my ImportWordTable macro is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", tableNo)
    End If

    resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see if the loop references the first column at all?

Comment: @SamuelEverson what I was thinking is since I am looping through all the tables of the whole document, if I can identify which page is the current table i am reading then I could access the page header

Comment: @SamuelEverson what I was thinking is since I am looping through all the tables of the whole document, if I can identify which page is the current table i am reading then I could access the page header

Comment: Ah i misunderstood where the names were I'm sorry! The [headerfooter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.headerfooter) object may be of use (i've not used it before though sorry) otherwise you could achieve the header details with the [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmarks) object. I can add some sample code for importing bookmark text from word to excel once i'm on my PC if you need it. Let me know.